# NewNetIPAddress: ActiveStore vs. PersistantStore

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting, system-administration

I'm trying to set a new IP-Address by using a powershell script. I use this command:

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $interfaceName -IPAddress $_.IPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixLength $maskLegth
```

However, on a disconnected interface i get this error:

```
New-NetIPAddress : Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled
```

But when i set the -PolicyStore to ActiveStore, the script will run without errors:

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $interfaceName -IPAddress $_.IPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixLength $maskLegth  -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

I'm not quite sure what this property does, since after restart the settings still are in place. Are there any drawbacks here? Or why does this error even come up?

Comment: It is interesting that applying the command to *only* the `ActiveStore` makes for success, even when [applied to a disconnected interface](https://www.darrylvanderpeijl.com/inconsistent-parameters-policystore-persistentstore-and-dhcp-enabled/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
New-NetIPAddress : Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled
```

PersistentStore is separate from ActiveStore, and there is also separate GPO store.

These stores are firewall and network configurations.

ActiveStore contains configuration for this computer.
GPO store is configuration from local group policy.
Active store is curentlly active configuration, and includes both GPO and Persistent store.

Problem you are getting is because Persistent store is set to DHCP and you are configuring static address, which makes not sense.

first disable DHCP in active store and then set IP for interface.

For information about these stores and how to set them see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallsetting?view=win10-ps